# XPages ftsearch results for combobox fields

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I created on my previous applications a simple FTsearch module, displaying the results inside a `viewPanel1`.

But, now in other app it gives me a headache. The `search` code from the view:

```
var tmpArray = new Array("");
var cTerms = 0; 

if (sessionScope.searchFurnizor) { 
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(Field txt_particontractcv_1 = \"*" + sessionScope.searchFurnizor + "*\")"; 
} 


if (sessionScope.searchStare) { 
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(Field txt_stadiucontrcv = \"*" + sessionScope.searchStare + "*\")"; 
}

qstring = tmpArray.join(" AND ").trim(); 
sessionScope.queryString = qstring; 
return qstring
```

The `txt_particontractcv_1` is a simple inputText and `txt_stadiucontrcv` is a checkbox:

```
  <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" value="#{Contr.txt_stadiucontrcv}" defaultValue="In derulare">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="In derulare" itemValue="In derulare"
                                id="selectItem1">
            </xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Finalizat" itemValue="Finalizat"
                                        id="selectItem2">
            </xp:selectItem>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

The button which submits the search is doing a partial refresh to `viewPanel1`. Still, it returns 0 results even there are documents respecting the filter criteria inside the search.

**LATER EDIT:** After deleting one by one fields from the FTsearch module, I think I found the issue: the problem is at the fields which are comboboxes ( my case ) in the document content but also inside the FTsearch modulo. The code for the combobox from the FTsearch:

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" value="#{sessionScope.searchStare}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="In derulare" itemValue="In derulare" id="selectItem1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Finalizat" itemValue="Finalizat" id="selectItem2">
    </xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Also, I noticed that the inputField(s) must be inputText, I try with some comoboboxes as input fields, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing the view in the partialrefresh or a panel outside of the view?
because if you are refreshing the view you probably never update the search query. If so add an xp:panel or xp:div out side of the view and do the partial refresh on that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion, though in other application the view isn't on panel/div and the search results are displaying correctly.

Comment: I tried, same result. Hmm, it must be something wrong in my code I guess.

Comment: as Paul suggested get the search string and try in in the same view in notes

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a full text search is not working how you expect it to, my recommendation is always to print out the search string. Then try performing the search in a view in the Notes Client.

If it doesn't work in the view in the client, trying to resolve it in your XPage will not get it working. The Notes Client will tell you why, usually "Query is not understandable" and you can troubleshoot why using the buttons in the search bar in Notes, which tells you which fields are available and what data type the UNK table thinks they are.

If it does work, there's a problem somewhere in your XPage.

As ever, break it down to try to identify where the problem is - in this case the full text search functionality or the implementation of it in XPages.

Comment: I noticed that the inputField(s) must be inputText, I try with some comoboboxes as input fields, but not working.

Comment: Please confirm if the search query works in Notes Client view

Comment: In notes client I get also no results, using a combobox as a input field for the search query. I don't get, altough, any "Query is not understandable" message.

Comment: Are you printing your query out and pasting it into the Search bar in Notes Client or opening the XPage in Notes Client? My request was to print the query your code builds, paste it into the Search bar in a view of the database in Notes Client and check results. The Search bar doesn't allow you to add comboboxes or input fields, just a search query along the lines of FIELD firstName = "Test"

Comment: I see now. I will try, I had never did this, hope to get it fix.